# nested loops results bunched together Python

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

```
for j in range(10):
    for i in range(10):
        print(j,end=" ")
```

My results are bunched together and I need to have 10 numbers per line. I cant use a `print("0123456789")`. I have tried `print(j,j,j,j,j,j,j,j,j)` and I get the results that I'm looking for but I'm sure this isn't the proper way to write the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `print(j,j,j,j,j,j,j,j,j)` works then you simply need to add another `print()` after each iteration:

```
for j in range(10):
    for i in range(10):
        print(j,end=" ")
    print()
```

Output:

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 
2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 
3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 
4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 
5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 
6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 
7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 
8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 
9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9
```

Or simply:

```
for j in range(10):
    print(" ".join(str(j) * 10))

0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3
4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4
5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5
6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6
7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7
8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8
9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9
```

Comment: I think this is what OP is looking for!

Comment: @Kasra, based on the `j,j,j,j,j,j,j,j,j,j` it seems so but you never know!

Comment: `.join()` isn't efficient on a gen exp as it has to make two passes over the data - the first pass is to calculate the total string length. So it's better to use it on a list comprehension instead. OTOH, efficiency is hardly an issue here, and the gen exp form is easier to read. But I think we've had this conversation before. :)

Comment: @PM2Ring, I normally use a list but as you mentioned I don't think efficiency is an issue.

Comment: Thank you Padraic Cunningham!! I figured out a way to do it with '\n' but your way is much more efficient. I had tried something similar but indented the final print incorrectly. Thanks again!!!

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using a nested for loop when you can use a single for loop:

```
for i in range(10):
    print('{} '.format(i) * 10)
```

Comment: @PM2Ring Corrected now.

Comment: Fine. Hopefully, they won't care about the trailing space. :)

Answer (score 0):

This is similar to Malik Brahimi's solution, except it doesn't put a space after the last digit on each line:

```
for i in range(10):
    print(' '.join([str(i)]*10))
```

**output**

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3
4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4
5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5
6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6
7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7
8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8
9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9
```

Just for fun, here's another way to do it with a single loop, this time using a format string with numbered fields.

```
fmt = ('{0} ' * 10)[:-1]
for i in range(10):
    print(fmt.format(i))
```